# Restart Ratchet websockets automatically

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I have an issue with an old WebSocket system. It's build on Ubuntu 14.04 with Php 5.4 and using Ratchet. We are experiencing that WebSockets stop working in a month or two. When we restart the WebSockets things go back to normal.

I believe this issue is due to the overload of the user's connection. I want to have a script that detects this overload and restarts the WebSockets service using the `supervisor`.

I used the following commands to restart it:

```
>>Commands to kill background process
$ ps -ef | grep supervisord
$ sudo kill -s SIGTERM 9384

Restart the WebSockets to run in the background
$ sudo supervisord -c supervisor.conf
```

What do you think is causing the issue?

Error logs issues:

```
[Mon Apr 13 18:57:34.357822 2020] [:error] [pid 27023] [client 127.0.0.1:43760] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 82 bytes) in /var/www/html/webservices/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php on line 153
[Tue Apr 14 02:10:41.075838 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 3617] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Tue Apr 14 03:22:07.072937 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 4922] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Tue Apr 14 18:21:52.864750 2020] [:error] [pid 6628] [client 127.0.0.1:34265] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81 bytes) in /var/www/html/webservices/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php on line 153
[Tue Apr 14 22:33:53.375819 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 14950] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Wed Apr 15 16:06:11.168718 2020] [:error] [pid 19246] [client 127.0.0.1:49378] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/html/webservices/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php on line 153
[Wed Apr 15 23:28:21.148510 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 27390] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Thu Apr 16 01:05:48.520618 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 28378] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Thu Apr 16 14:48:42.128930 2020] [:error] [pid 30021] [client 127.0.0.1:36520] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 128 bytes) in /var/www/html/webservices/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php on line 153
[Thu Apr 16 18:00:24.425987 2020] [:error] [pid 4302] [client 127.0.0.1:41767] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ServerException' with message 'Server error: `POST https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/delete` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response' in /var/www/html/webservices/application/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/webservices/application/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response))\n#1 /var/www/html/webservices/application/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response))\n#2 /var/www/html/webservices/application/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response), Array)\n#3 /var/www/html/webservices/application/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise::GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\{closure}()\n#4 /var/www/html/webserv in /var/www/html/webservices/application/vendor/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/src/Dropbox/Http/Clients/DropboxGuzzleHttpClient.php on line 59
[Thu Apr 16 23:45:36.114882 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 7753] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Fri Apr 17 09:19:14.032025 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 12322] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Fri Apr 17 15:29:58.370035 2020] [:error] [pid 10771] [client 127.0.0.1:52465] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/html/webservices/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_result.php on line 153
[Fri Apr 17 20:38:41.862722 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 19076] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
[Sat Apr 18 07:01:04.956983 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 23882] (110)Connection timed out: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8443 (localhost) failed
[Sat Apr 18 07:01:04.957045 2020] [proxy:error] [pid 23882] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s
[Sat Apr 18 07:01:04.957056 2020] [proxy_wstunnel:error] [pid 23882] [client 129.205.113.147:4058] AH02452: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
[Sat Apr 18 12:37:54.338291 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 27365] [client 129.28.175.79:45909] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/.php
[Sat Apr 18 16:28:38.481429 2020] [:error] [pid 24606] [client 127.0.0.1:40566] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /var/www/html/webservices/application/models/webservice_model.php on line 1011
[Sat Apr 18 22:45:45.094137 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 32644] AH02032: Hostname <host ip>:443 provided via SNI and hostname <host ip> provided via HTTP are different
```

Comment: Please add error logs pertinent to issue to your question.

Comment: @user254694 posted errors, I found. Among all I found only 1 error `(110)Connection timed out: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8443 (localhost) failed` I think it belongs to WebSockets.

Comment: The error is pretty obvious your server is using the full 1go of ram its allowed to use, either increase the ram or debug the elements that are consuming too much memory and improve them, 1Go is not huge but it is not a small amount for a ws server as well, how much connections are you receiving because there might be a small memory leak as well

Comment: I'd start by monitoring the ram usage over time, it will tell you if there is a leak or just a peak in connection, if the later double your ram otherwise finding the cause of the leak is a complex process with xgrind